# В массиве а найти максимумы из каждых четырех элементов и записать их в новый массив b

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

В массиве а найти максимумы из каждых четырех элементов и записать их в новый массив b. Подскажите алгоритм, код который имею на данный момент:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 12
#define MIN_VALUE 0
#define MAX_VALUE 100
#define Random(min, max) (min + rand() % ((max + 1) - min))
using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a[SIZE], b[3];
    int i, max = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        a[i] = Random(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);
    cout << "Source array: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        cout << " " << a[i];
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (a[j] > b[0]) b[0] = a[j];
        }
    }
    cout << endl << "Array b: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        cout << " " << b[i];

    cout << max;
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: А теперь, вместо последнего цикла в Вашем коде, объясните словами как бы Вы это делали вручную - на бумаге.

Comment: Поиск максимума в случайно наполненном массиве. Послушайте, ну разве это выход - пытаться приспособить то, чего сами не понимаете, под свою задачу?... Может, стоит **самому** поработать?

Comment: @Igor А что собственно объяснять? Проверял бы каждое значение, подходит ли оно под условие, в этом случае больше ли оно предыдущего значения максимума. Нужно отделить 4 таких цикла и как-то сделать это 3 раза, записав последнее значение в новый массив.

Comment: Хм. Хорошо. Сделайте это. Получилось? Значит, все-таки надо объяснять.

Comment: @Igor получилось и...? что дальше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> и как-то сделать это 3 раза

Вы же не домохозяйка, а программу хотите написать.

Вам надо получить три максимума, то есть какие-то сходные действия надо выполнить три раза. Это, наверное, будет цикл из трех итераций.

Внутри каждой итерации надо выбрать максимум из четырех чисел. Это, наверное, еще один цикл внутри первого.

---

Очень хорошо. Тут, я смотрю, можно одним циклом обойтись.

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
{
    int j = i / 4;
    if (j * 4 == i || a[i] > b[j])
        b[j] = a[i];
}
```

Comment: Обновил код, но нужна помощь. Как сделать что бы цикл повторялся после 4 действий другого цикла?

Comment: Что и требовалось. Спасибо ;)

Comment: Не знал что можно использовать ` b[i / 4] ` именно так

Comment: Ну конечно один цикл нужен всего...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>//добавил еще эту библиотеку для команды max()
#define SIZE 12
#define MIN_VALUE 0
#define MAX_VALUE 100
#define Random(mi, ma) (mi + rand() % ((ma + 1) - mi))
using namespace std;

int main() {
srand(time(NULL));
int a[SIZE], b[3];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    a[i] = Random(MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE);
cout << "Source array: " << endl;
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    cout << " " << a[i];
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i += 4) {
    b[i / 4] = max(max(a[i], a[i + 1]), max(a[i + 2],a[i + 3]));//находим максимум в каждых 4 елементах
}
//готово в масиве b максимальное из каждых 4 елементов масива a
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Код не работает.

Comment: Уже поправил. Если что удали #include "pch.h"